# How to setup monodoc to work with transifex.com?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, documentation

monodoc is the only C# system, which work on mono on linux. Sandcastle fails - https://github.com/ArsenShnurkov/sandcastle-tools/issues/1

The goal is to get multilanguage HTML documentation for API.

How to setup development with monodoc and transefix.com (which is opensource translation platform) for hello-world project?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question;  The best course of action would be to extract the strings from the various XML nodes (those inside Docs/) and put them on a .po file, translate that, and then produce a translated version out of it.